# Searching for letter combinations in a string php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

i am trying to write a program in php that looks for "au" letter combinations within a string, if found, it should echo "1" if not echo "2". My problem is on my if condition. Any ideas?

```
<?php 

$word = "csa";
$b = str_split($word);
$length = count($word);
for ($i = 0; $i< $length; $i++) {
   if ($b[$i] = "a" & $b[$i+1] = "u")
      echo "1";
   else
      echo "2";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$b[i] = "a"` This assigns `"a"` to `$b[i]`. for equality check use `===`

Comment: And use the `&&` operator instead of `&`.

Comment: Why don't you use [**`strpos`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you actually should do like thos

```
if (strpos($word,'au') !== false) {
      echo '1';
 } else {
      echo '2';
}
```

Comment: This will stop after the first hit.

Comment: I beleive he doesn't want to look multiple 'au' words and doesnt want to print '1' multiple times

Comment: Not sure; just stating the facts if someone isn't aware of it.